# How to trim a Bleeding Heart?

Tags: pruning, bleeding-hearts

We have a [*Lamprocapnos spectabilis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamprocapnos) or Bleeding Heart plant which has become quite large. I need to trim it back some. Does this type of plant receive getting pruned very well? How much can I trim it back? Any worries on doing this? The plant is established as this is its second year in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular plant sometimes becomes what's known as 'summer dormant', meaning all the foliage dies back below ground in summer (usually late June/or July) anyway, though whether it does so or not is variable, so cutting it back won't do it any harm at all. Take off what you need to - this might encourage more growth, or it might encourage dormancy, hard to say. I'd add, though, if its too large for where it is already, only in its second year and only end of May, you might want to consider moving it in autumn to another position where it has more room.

Comment: I second what Bamboo says about moving the plant. In my experience Bleeding Hearts expand fairly quick for the first 5 years or so. If you think the 2 year old plant is too big you'd best move it before you find out how big it is a few years from now.